# how to add google translator in an angular 2 application?

Tags: angular

```
<div class="m-content">
    <h1>My Web Page</h1>

    <p>Hello everybody!</p>

    <p>Translate this page:</p>

    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what my code looks like ... to get you started. NOTE: This is *not* secure nor is it "production ready". It is just a little sample app to get started using the API.

NOTE: This is Angular v6 and not compatible with Angular v2.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TranslateResponse } from './translate';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslateService {
  private API_KEY = 'your key here';
  private translateUrl = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key='+this.API_KEY;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  translate(textToTranslate: string, target: string): Observable<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    });

    const body = {
      'q': textToTranslate,
      'source': 'en',
      'target': target
    }

    return this.http.post<any>(this.translateUrl, body, { headers: headers }).pipe(
      tap(result => console.log('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result))),
      map(result => result.data.translations[0].translatedText),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Used your headers, body and translateUrl with a valid Apikey - Worked like a charm! Thank you :)